# When scroll card view fastly Resources$NotFoundException exception found

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I developing android app with card view , in card view fragment found.
when I scroll fastly up and down this exception found :

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xc
        at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:2710)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

from adapter :

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final StatisticsItem current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(data.get(position).Title);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    holder.layout.removeAllViews();
    holder.layout.addView(ll);
    int id = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
    ll.setId(id);

    fragment = new ChartsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("type", data.get(position).ChartType);
    args.putSerializable("AnalysisItem", analysisData.get(data.get(position).ChartType));
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(ll.getId(), fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    holder.ExistPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            analysisItemLinster.doAnalysisAction(1, current.Id);

        }
    });

}
```

onCreateViewHolder :

```
   public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.statistics_card_row, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}
```

The card view in fragment , and every card have a fragment to show chart

Pic from app

http://im87.gulfup.com/l6nrkF.jpg

Comment: Never instantiate anything in onBindViewHolder (LinearLayout), forget about layout operation inside this method, I don't like fragment parts also... This method is problably most often run and I believe it is slowed abnormally with this operations. Please tell us how Cards should look like and add onCreateViewHolder method. In which line exception is raised? Attach full stacktrace

Comment: I updated the questions

Comment: Please Attach stacktrace (where exactly is you application crashing). Please study how to use viewholder correctly, include your LinearLayout to statistics_card_row.xml do not create it in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: I don't know exactly where the app crashed, but I guess its in the adapter. I added the full crash.

Comment: Attach 'statistics_card_row.xml' your code probably crashes because of generating id for your LinearLayout and it cannot be retrieved. You need to correctly write 'statistics_card_row.xml' and do not create new views in onBindViewHolder method